# What is the best way to identify chosen button by x, y

Tags: c#

I am making a chess game in windows form and after I made it so I once a button is pressed I will get his place on the board so I can use math on it (Like if I want to find the square exactly in front of a square I can just find the square with y +1)

```
void button64_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (partOfTurn == false)
            {
                Xa = 8;
                Ya = 8;
                partOfTurn = true;
            }

            if (partOfTurn == true)
            {
                Xb = 8;
                Yb = 8;
                partOfTurn = false;
                Click();
            }
        }
```

I need a way to change the second button's background image into the first one's and to clear the first one but in order to do so with 
`button1.BackgroundImage = button2.backgroundImage`

I need to use the name of the button. How can I do this without doing it in a switch with 4096 cases of any button combination?

Comment: So, is your board 64 square buttons? If so, I'd name the buttons in a way that I could easily discern the coordinates ("x1y1" through "x8y8").  I'd make a single button click handler handle all clicks, and figure out what was happening by looking at `(sender as Button)?.Name`.  I'd track what the last button pressed was and what the coordinate of that button was (so I could figure out if moving that knight is legal).  I'd also provide a function that lets me get button coordinates (as an int pair) from a button and get the right button from a pair of coordinates.

Comment: How have you created your buttons? How have you wired up the event handlers? How many buttons do you have? Why are there 4096 button combinations?

Comment: Just a hint - if you've dragged and dropped the buttons using the designer then you've made your life hard. If you use a loop to create them and save the buttons in a `List<Button>` then your life is easy.

Comment: Oh, and you probably want one or a few `enum`s.  For example `enum Piece {Rook, Knight, Bishop, King, Queen, Pawn}` and maybe `enum Player {White, Black}`.  That way, you can write your rules in a much more natural way (for example, a `LegalMoves` function that returns a list of int pairs given a `Piece`, a `Player` and a current position (as an int pair).

Comment: @Enigmativity: Though `List<T>` is almost always better than an Array of T, in this case, it might make sense to store the buttons in a two-dimensional Button array: `Button[,]`

Comment: @Flydog57 - IMHO it rarely makes sense to use a two dimensional array. It's almost always better to use a jaggard array (i.e. `Button[][]`) as you can index it just as efficiently and you can use LINQ queries against it.

Comment: You can always use the good ole Tag property.  It is an object so you could store a Point type in each button Tag. A Point has an X and Y property.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is for learning I'll not solve it but just rather give a hint:

The sender object you get passed as a parameter is basically the object you call the event handler on, in your case the clicked button itself.

```
private void buttonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
     Button clickedButton = (Button) sender; 
 }
```

Comment: Can you please explain more? Again, I am very new to c# and I am having trouble understanding you

Comment: How can I use button sender and still be able to identify what button was used?

Answer (score 0):

The `Tag` property of each Button is an object. You could use a Point or create your own class. I have named mine Coord but it could be Position or Square. You could also use chess notation a1, c2, although using numbers is easier to determine relations between squares.

(Coord could perhaps be extended to include the chess notation as a property, and anything else useful.)

```
public class Coord
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Coord(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Button previousButton = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        button1.Click += Buttons_Click;
        button2.Click += Buttons_Click;

        button1.Tag = new Coord(0, 0);
        button2.Tag = new Coord(1, 0);
    }

    private void Buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (previousButton != null)
        {
            // do something with previousButton
            Coord prevCoords = (Coord)(previousButton.Tag);

            MessageBox.Show($"previous coords {prevCoords.X} {prevCoords.Y}");
        }

        // code to work with the currently clicked button
        // as (Button)sender
        Coord currentCoords = (Coord)((Button)sender).Tag;
        MessageBox.Show($"current coords {currentCoords.X} {currentCoords.Y}");

        // remember the current button
        previousButton = (Button)sender;
    }
}
```

You would still store the buttons in a collection but I haven't included that aspect in my sample code.